# How to stay on the same page layout when clicking the link?

Tags: web, hyperlink

Hi stackoverflow community. I have a page with lest of articles' overviews with associated links. I want user to stay on the same page when he clicks the link but instead of having a list of articles he will get to the full article. Not quite sure how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of web page behavior, you'd use JavaScript DOM manipulation with Ajax requests. JavaScript frameworks such as jQuery have very good support for this. You will need to handle navigation sensibly, so that hitting the back button does the expected thing, but the frameworks support this, too. Try out some tutorials for the various frameworks to see which one suits you best.

Comment: Thank you Hans-Martin Mosner. Will check some tutorials.

Comment: Just have watched tutorial on Frames, I am not sure this is exactly what I need as it divides the page to sections. My goal is to have another page opened in the browser but saving the header of the page. So, let's say I have four links in the header 'Home' 'About' 'Articles' 'News'. Let's say user is on 'Articles' page and checks articles list, after he clicked on the article he gets to the full article but still can see all the links on the top of the page (mentioned above). And I want him technically still be on 'Articles' page.

Comment: HTML Frames are certainly not what you need, they're technology of the last century. Have you looked at jQuery or one of the other JavaScript frameworks at all?